# Adding line chart for every category dynamically using xlsxwriter

Tags: xlsxwriter

I am trying to create a line chart with multiple categories using xlsxwriter. I am however unable to add multiple categories as shown in the below image

[image: Line chart with category]

The below code adds a line chart

```
df.add_series({
    'categories': f'=(\'data\'!$D$4:$D${4 + len(data)})',
    'name': f'=(\'data\'!$E$4:$E${4 + len(data)})',
    'values': f'=(\'data\'!$F$4:$F${4 + len(data)})',
})
```

But I am unable to a line for each category.

Comment: In general you need to add a new series for each line/data you wish to plot. The categories should be the same for each one but the values range would change. However, there are a lot of errors in the code you show: the range probably shouldn't include brackets; the name should be a single cell not a range; `add_series()` isn't a method that can be called on a dataframe. Also, for variable values/categories you should use the array syntax rather than the string range syntax.

Comment: Have a look at the [XlsxWriter working with Charts docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html) and the various [chart examples](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart_examples.html).